# How to determine which value has a smaller index in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

For a calculator I'm making I have an array with operators in which I need to know whether the times sign comes before or after the division sign. for this I had the following code (using JQuery's inArray):

```
if ($.inArray('*', operators) < $.inArray(':', operators)) {
    //Multiplication is before division so perform mulitplication
}
else {
    //Division is before multiplication so perform division
}
```

Now this code runs in a loop, and every time it removes the operator it has found from the array. This means that at some point there could be only multiplications in the array and no divisions. In the case the inArray function will return for example 3 for the multiplication, and -1 for the division. What you get:

```
if (3 < -1) ---> false
```

So it thinks it has found a division sign, where there is none.

It also has to work when it's the other way around: no mulitplication, but only division(s).

I can't come up with solutions to fix this, so that brought me here.

Answer (score 0):

Test whether there's any division first:

```
if ($.inArray(':', operators) == -1 || $.inArray('*', operators) < $.inArray(':', operators)) {
```

Comment: This will evaluate to false, because when there's no division `$.inArray(':', operators) != -1` will be false, so everything will be false.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not use a hash which uses the operators (string) as keys and returns a precedence level (integer) as value?

Some operators have the same precedence level, like plus and minus.

Here is the [precedence table for C++ operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), which is much more than you need, but should give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

One quick and dirty fix is to add an additional check for a '-1' return.

```
var divIndex = $.inArray(":", operators)
var multiIndex == $.inArray('*', operators)

if (divIndex != -1 && multiIndex < divIndex) {
  // multiplication is before division
} else if (divIndex == -1 && multiIndex != -1) {
  // only multiplication left
} else if (divIndex != -1 && divIndex < multiIndex) {
  // division before multiplication
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
if ($.inArray('*', operators) < $.inArray(':', operators) || $.inArray(':', operators < 0)) {
  ...
```